# In MATLAB, how can I do the sample discrete distribution?

Tags: matlab

I have a probability, in which I have three numbers, 1, 2, and 3. Each of them are selected in 1/3 chance.

How can I make a function for this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

This function should be sufficient:

```
randi(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function rand returns a random number (or matrix of numbers) uniformly distributed in interval (0,1).

You can convert this to your range using

```
ceil(rand()*3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using randsample for other situations. See question and answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/507795/simulation-of-custom-probability-distribution-in-matlab):